# Calling Grails def from Javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax, tomcat, grails, groovy

I'm attempting to make an `ajax` request to a very simple Grails method:

```
def countRace() {
    Date date = params.date("date", 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    Integer count = Race.countByDate(date);
    log.info("Number of races on " + date + " is " + count);
    return [count : count]
}
```

And I am using the following jQuery code to do it:

```
function updateDayRaceCount(id) {
    $.ajax({
       url: "${g.createLink(controller:'data', action:'countRace')}?date=" + id
    }).done(function(response) {
       alert(response);
    });
}
```

I am seeing the logs fire on the server, so I know the method is being hit:

```
grails.app.controllers.runnerdb.DataController Number of races on Thu Mar 06 00:00:00 GMT 2014 is 38
```

But the ajax request is erroring out with a `404`. When I observed the error, I found that it was the `Tomcat` standard 404 page, and the URL that was being generated, that looks like this:

```
/runnerdb/data/countRace?date=<id here>
```

Was being mapped to:

```
 /runnerdb/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/data/countRace.jsp
```

This is where the issue is, because I imagine Tomcat or grails are trying to render a non-existent view.

**My question is..**

How to I stop this kind of behaviour in grails for just this one method, and force it to simply return the `int` value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Grails resolves views by convention. In your case you will need to use render instead of return. By using return you are telling Grails to continue the processing to a view using your return as the model.

Here is an example of rendering a text value:

```
render(text: count)
```

Alternatively you may want to render your results as JSON (provided you import the converter):

```
render [count: count] as JSON
```

Comment: Instantly solved the issue. I swear, one day I'll get the hang of this!